# Playing video using textureview in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, android-recyclerview, android-textureview

I am trying to implement a list with videos like vine or Instagram app. Where they play video plays when list item is shown or fully visible and video pauses when list item gets hided. I am using textureview with media player to play a video from url and added it as list item in recyclerview. Following is my code.

VideosAdapter Class:

```
public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
private ArrayList<String> urls;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public LinearLayout layout;
    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}

public VideosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> urls) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urls = urls;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public VideosAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_main, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String url = urls.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(url);
    playVideo(holder, url);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

private void playVideo(ViewHolder holder, String url)
{
    final CustomVideoPlayer vid = new CustomVideoPlayer(String.valueOf(url), context);
    holder.layout.addView(vid);
    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            vid.changePlayState();
        }
    });
}
}
```

CustomVideoPlayer Class:

```
public class CustomVideoPlayer extends  TextureView implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener
{

Context context;
String url;
MediaPlayer mp;
Surface surface;
SurfaceTexture s;

public CustomVideoPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
}

public CustomVideoPlayer(String ur, Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    this.url = ur;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surface, int arg1, int arg2) {

    this.s = surface;
    Log.d("url", this.url);
    startVideo(surface);
}
@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture arg0) {

    return true;
}
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture arg0, int arg1,int arg2) {
}
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture arg0) {
}

public void setVideo(String url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

public void startVideo(SurfaceTexture t)
{
    this.surface = new Surface(t);
    this.mp = new MediaPlayer();
    this.mp.setSurface(this.surface);
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(this.url);
        this.mp.setDataSource(url);
        this.mp.prepareAsync();

        this.mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();

            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void changePlayState()
{
    if(this.mp.isPlaying())
        this.mp.pause();
    else
        this.mp.start();
}
}
```

When i run this code there are multiple issues in it.

1) First two items/videos buffers and play fine. But when i scroll it does not load third video and first video also gets removed from the list.

2) On scroll videos/list items starts buffering again for the item that was already buffered.

3) On fast scroll list gets too laggy and get stuck and crashes.

Attached is the image of logcat that i get while list scroll and video playing.

[image]

Can anyone guide me through this? What is the right way to create a list like vine app?

Comment: There is a device-dependent limit on the number of simultaneous videos. Make sure you're stopping playback of the previous video before starting playback on a new one. The 'M' release is scheduled to add an API that will tell you what the limit is -- http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#video .

Comment: Thanks for response. I have added 3 urls to play. But didn't started the playback and commented this line mp.start(); from startVideo(surface) method. I am getting the issue of listview gets stuck for 5-6 seconds when i scroll. Why i am getting this If this issue is related to playback or playing multiple videos at a time as now i am just preparing all videos but haven't started playback yet.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to achieve that by first downloading the videos from url and then playing it with custom player. Here is how i did in case if anyone else needed that:

1) Get all url's need to be played

2) Start downloading videos (in queue) from urls in local storage and keep a flag in preferences (that a video is already downloaded or not)

3) Assign urls to Adapter in which initialize object of video player controller that handles video playbacks

4) Set addOnScrollListener to check which position/video is currently visible and check if video is already downloaded or not if yes then play it.

Following is complete code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements IVideoDownloadListener {

private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

private Context context;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private VideosAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ArrayList<Video> urls;
VideosDownloader videosDownloader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = MainActivity.this;
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    urls = new ArrayList<Video>();
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new VideosAdapter(MainActivity.this, urls);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    videosDownloader = new VideosDownloader(context);
    videosDownloader.setOnVideoDownloadListener(this);

    if(Utils.hasConnection(context))
    {
        getVideoUrls();

        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                    int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                    Video video;
                    if (urls != null && urls.size() > 0)
                    {
                        if (findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
                            video = urls.get(findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition);
                            mAdapter.videoPlayerController.setcurrentPositionOfItemToPlay(findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition);
                            mAdapter.videoPlayerController.handlePlayBack(video);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            video = urls.get(firstVisiblePosition);
                            mAdapter.videoPlayerController.setcurrentPositionOfItemToPlay(firstVisiblePosition);
                            mAdapter.videoPlayerController.handlePlayBack(video);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(context, "No internet available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onVideoDownloaded(Video video) {
    mAdapter.videoPlayerController.handlePlayBack(video);
}

private void getVideoUrls()
{
    Video video1 = new Video("0", "1", "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
    urls.add(video1);
    Video video2 = new Video("1", "2", "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
    urls.add(video2);
    Video video3 = new Video("2", "3", "http://sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4");
    urls.add(video3);
    Video video4 = new Video("3", "4", "http://dev.exiv2.org/attachments/341/video-2012-07-05-02-29-27.mp4");
    urls.add(video4);
    Video video5 = new Video("4", "5", "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
    urls.add(video5);
    Video video6 = new Video("5", "6", "http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
    urls.add(video6);
    Video video7 = new Video("6", "7", "http://sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4");
    urls.add(video7);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    videosDownloader.startVideosDownloading(urls);
 }
}
```

**VideosAdapter**

```
public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static String TAG = "VideosAdapter";

Context context;
private ArrayList<Video> urls;
public VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textView;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    public RelativeLayout layout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    }
}

public VideosAdapter(Context context, final ArrayList<Video> urls) {

    this.context = context;
    this.urls = urls;
    videoPlayerController = new VideoPlayerController(context);
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_main, parent, false);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    int screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp; //The current width of the available screen space, in dp units, corresponding to screen width resource qualifier.
    int smallestScreenWidthDp = configuration.smallestScreenWidthDp; //The smallest screen size an application will see in normal operation, corresponding to smallest screen width resource qualifier.

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    int screenWidthPixels = Utils.convertDpToPixel(screenWidthDp, context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, screenWidthPixels);
    viewHolder.layout.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);

    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Video video = urls.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText("Video " + video.getId());

    final VideoPlayer videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    videoPlayer.setLayoutParams(params);

    holder.layout.addView(videoPlayer);
    videoPlayerController.loadVideo(video, videoPlayer, holder.progressBar);
    videoPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            videoPlayer.changePlayState();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewRecycledCalled");
    holder.layout.removeAllViews();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

}
```

**VideosDownloader**

```
public class VideosDownloader {

private static String TAG = "VideosDownloader";

Context context;
FileCache fileCache;
IVideoDownloadListener iVideoDownloadListener;

public VideosDownloader(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Start downloading all videos from given urls

public void startVideosDownloading(final ArrayList<Video> videosList)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i=0; i<videosList.size(); i++)
            {
                final Video video = videosList.get(i);
                String id = video.getId();
                String url = video.getUrl();

                String isVideoDownloaded = Utils.readPreferences(context, video.getUrl(), "false");
                boolean isVideoAvailable = Boolean.valueOf(isVideoDownloaded);
                if(!isVideoAvailable)
                {
                    //Download video from url
                    String downloadedPath = downloadVideo(url);
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Vides downloaded at: " + downloadedPath);
                    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Utils.savePreferences(context, video.getUrl(), "true");
                             iVideoDownloadListener.onVideoDownloaded(video);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

private String downloadVideo(String urlStr)
{
    URL url = null;
    File file = null;
    try
    {
        file = fileCache.getFile(urlStr);
        url = new URL(urlStr);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        URLConnection ucon = null;
        ucon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

        //Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to read(-1)
        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
        }

        //clean up
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inStream.close();

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}


public void setOnVideoDownloadListener(IVideoDownloadListener iVideoDownloadListener) {
    this.iVideoDownloadListener = iVideoDownloadListener;
}
}
```

**VideoPlayerController**

```
public class VideoPlayerController {

private static String TAG = "VideoPlayerController";

Context context;
FileCache fileCache;
int currentPositionOfItemToPlay = 0;
Video currentPlayingVideo;

private Map<String, VideoPlayer> videos = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<String, VideoPlayer>());
private Map<String, ProgressBar> videosSpinner = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<String, ProgressBar>());

public VideoPlayerController(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
}

public void loadVideo(Video video, VideoPlayer videoPlayer, ProgressBar progressBar) {

    //Add video to map
    videos.put(video.getIndexPosition(), videoPlayer);
    videosSpinner.put(video.getIndexPosition(), progressBar);

    handlePlayBack(video);
}

//This method would check two things
//First if video is downloaded or its local path exist
//Second if the videoplayer of this video is currently showing in the list or visible

public void handlePlayBack(Video video)
{
    //Check if video is available
    if(isVideoDownloaded(video))
    {

        // then check if it is currently at a visible or playable position in the listview
        if(isVideoVisible(video))
        {
            //IF yes then playvideo
            playVideo(video);
        }
    }
}

private void playVideo(final Video video)
{
    //Before playing it check if this video is already playing

    if(currentPlayingVideo != video)
    {
        //Start playing new url
        if(videos.containsKey(video.getIndexPosition()))
        {
            final VideoPlayer videoPlayer2 = videos.get(video.getIndexPosition());
            String localPath = fileCache.getFile(video.getUrl()).getAbsolutePath();
            if(!videoPlayer2.isLoaded)
            {
                videoPlayer2.loadVideo(localPath, video);
                videoPlayer2.setOnVideoPreparedListener(new IVideoPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoPrepared(Video mVideo) {

                        //Pause current playing video if any
                        if(video.getIndexPosition() == mVideo.getIndexPosition())
                        {
                            if(currentPlayingVideo!=null)
                            {
                                VideoPlayer videoPlayer1 = videos.get(currentPlayingVideo.getIndexPosition());
                                videoPlayer1.pausePlay();
                            }
                            videoPlayer2.mp.start();
                            currentPlayingVideo = mVideo;
                        }


                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                //Pause current playing video if any
                if(currentPlayingVideo!=null)
                {
                    VideoPlayer videoPlayer1 = videos.get(currentPlayingVideo.getIndexPosition());
                    videoPlayer1.pausePlay();
                }

                boolean isStarted = videoPlayer2.startPlay();
                {
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Started playing Video Index: " + video.getIndexPosition());
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Started playing Video: " + video.getUrl());
                }
                currentPlayingVideo = video;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Log.i(TAG, "Already playing Video: " + video.getUrl());
    }

}

private boolean isVideoVisible(Video video) {

    //To check if the video is visible in the listview or it is currently at a playable position
    //we need the position of this video in listview and current scroll position of the listview
    int positionOfVideo = Integer.valueOf(video.getIndexPosition());

    if(currentPositionOfItemToPlay == positionOfVideo)
        return true;

    return false;
}

private boolean isVideoDownloaded(Video video) {

    String isVideoDownloaded = Utils.readPreferences(context, video.getUrl(), "false");
    boolean isVideoAvailable = Boolean.valueOf(isVideoDownloaded);
    if(isVideoAvailable)
    {
        //If video is downloaded then hide its progress
        hideProgressSpinner(video);
        return true;
    }

    showProgressSpinner(video);
    return false;
}

private void showProgressSpinner(Video video) {
    ProgressBar progressBar = videosSpinner.get(video.getIndexPosition());
    if(progressBar!=null)
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void hideProgressSpinner(Video video) {

    ProgressBar progressBar = videosSpinner.get(video.getIndexPosition());
    if(progressBar!=null && progressBar.isShown())
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i(TAG, "ProgressSpinner Hided Index: " + video.getIndexPosition());
    }
}

public void setcurrentPositionOfItemToPlay(int mCurrentPositionOfItemToPlay) {
    currentPositionOfItemToPlay = mCurrentPositionOfItemToPlay;
}
}
```

**VideoPlayer**

```
public class VideoPlayer extends TextureView implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

private static String TAG = "VideoPlayer";

/**This flag determines that if current VideoPlayer object is first item of the list if it is first item of list*/
boolean isFirstListItem;

boolean isLoaded;
boolean isMpPrepared;

IVideoPreparedListener iVideoPreparedListener;

Video video;
String url;
MediaPlayer mp;
Surface surface;
SurfaceTexture s;

public VideoPlayer(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VideoPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void loadVideo(String localPath, Video video) {

    this.url = localPath;
    this.video = video;
    isLoaded = true;

    if (this.isAvailable()) {
        prepareVideo(getSurfaceTexture());
    }

    setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    isMpPrepared = false;
    prepareVideo(surface);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {

    if(mp!=null)
    {
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
}

public void prepareVideo(SurfaceTexture t)
{

    this.surface = new Surface(t);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setSurface(this.surface);

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        mp.prepareAsync();

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                isMpPrepared = true;
                mp.setLooping(true);
                iVideoPreparedListener.onVideoPrepared(video);
            }


        });
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}

@Override
protected void onVisibilityChanged(View changedView, int visibility) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
}

public boolean startPlay()
{
    if(mp!=null)
        if(!mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.start();
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}

public void pausePlay()
{
    if(mp!=null)
        mp.pause();
}

public void stopPlay()
{
    if(mp!=null)
        mp.stop();
}

public void changePlayState()
{
    if(mp!=null)
    {
        if(mp.isPlaying())
            mp.pause();
        else
            mp.start();
    }

}

public void setOnVideoPreparedListener(IVideoPreparedListener iVideoPreparedListener) {
    this.iVideoPreparedListener = iVideoPreparedListener;
}
}
```

**IVideoDownloadListener**

```
public interface IVideoDownloadListener {
public void onVideoDownloaded(Video video);
}
```

**IVideoPreparedListener**

```
public interface IVideoPreparedListener {

public void onVideoPrepared(Video video);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nouman Bhatti. Can U please share this code as a single project. That's totally helps me.  Thank You.

Comment: Can you share your complete source code in working mode or mail me on test4fusioni@gmail.com.. Thanks

Comment: sorry guys i dont have complete source for it now as it was an old project. But above code is almost complete except xml files

Comment: can i set custom view xml for video item ? Becuase in My RecyclerView there are two cell one for video and another for images..

Comment: yes you can do it, but i haven't got your point exactly.  If you have separate cells for videoview and imageview then what is the issue?

Comment: can you send me view_main.xml ? so, i can explain it on detail.

Comment: what is FileCache here where is the filecache file?

Comment: @Sudhansu FileCache handles files that we were downloaded from provided URL's, that we use use later

Comment: You can make a custom class that will do the job

Comment: Is Video class of MediaStore.Video?

Comment: can you post your Video class?

Comment: @Dharmishtha sorry i dont have code available now, but i think Video was just a custom class to carry url and id

Comment: FileCache Class : https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/FileCache.java      & make Video class with (id,Indexposition and url) model class

Comment: Hi.This post i really helpful.Can you please tell how can I achieve the same functionality if I have different view types in recyclerview and videos are on different positions?

Comment: what do you mean by different view types? you can use any view type

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you add the custom video view in the layout file 'view_main' itself.
Check the visibility of the video view and  play only if the view is visible.

```
public static boolean isViewVisible(View subView, View parentView) {
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    parentView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
    if (subView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Code for checking visiblity. Call this in scroll state changed listener when the scroll state is idle.

Also you will have to use an AsyncTask for downloading videos ,but only download one video at a time or you might get out of memory error.

Comment: Cant use video view as it does not work with scrolling. Also can you elaborate where to call above method to get the visible listview item?

Comment: By video view I meant your custom view.

Comment: You will have to override onScrollListener of your list and get the top visible item. By the way r u using Recycler view or List view?

Comment: I am using recycler view

Comment: i cant do this because in that case i have only access of that view which is visible but on basis on visible view i also need to decide that next and previous views of visible view should stop and pause

Comment: @NoumanBhatti what Video object is being used in this sample? MediaStore.Video ?  If so Android Studio is saying there is no video.getIndexPosition() ?

Comment: @justdan0227 no it is custom Video class/object. You can create your own

Answer (score 4):

You should maintain a cache of videos locally by downloading them at backend and play one video at a time from local memory to keep the list scroll smooth.

Comment: What do you prefer to implement caching for videos? @sajad-khan