# How to play video in the middle of the RecyclerView list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I have multiple videos in the RecyclerView. I want when list focus in the middle the video must play automatically.

Comment: You mean when scrolling stops, play the video which is in the center of the page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978030/playing-video-using-textureview-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video-Player-Manager - it gives the ability to invoke MediaPlayer methods in a background thread. It has utilities to have only one playback when multiple media files are in the list. Before new playback starts, it stops the old playback and releases all the resources.

https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager

This may be useful to you

Comment: I have implemented these methods already. i just want to play the video in recyclerview in the middle of the screen

Comment: please see this link for recycler view plays the video in the center of the screen https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager#usage-in-scrolling-list-listview-recyclerview @ShikhaRatra